# the numbers Tr$(X^n)$ determine the conjugacy class of semisimple $X \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Tags: group-theory, trace

L.S.,

I am reading a paper of D. Blasius, where he states that the numbers Tr$(X^n) $ determine the conjugacy class of a semisimple element $X \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. I am having trouble proving this. I understand that for conjugate elements $A,B$ we have Tr$(A^n) =$ Tr$(B^n)$, it follows because $A = GBG^{-1}$ for some $G \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and Tr$(AG) =$ Tr$(GA)$. But unfortunately I don't know how to go around the other way! Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Willem

Comment: Being semisimple means being diagonalizable, and knowing all sums of powers of the eigenvalues is the same as knowing all the eigenvalues.

Comment: But knowing all the eigenvalues only determines the conjugacy when the eigenvalues are all distinct, right?

Comment: Knowing the eigenvalues with multiplicities will determine the conjugacy class when the element is diagonalizable.